# Insert multiple columns to the right in sequential order

Tags: excel, vba, insert, multiple-columns

**Aim**:
Selecting multiple columns, copying them and then inserting all copied columns each to its right.
**Example**:
Selection of columns A, B and C, and duplicating them in sequential order so that I end up with SIX columns where: A=B, C=D and E=F.

Any idea on how I can modify "Shift:=xlToRight" so  that columns are inserted to each one's right, rather than at the right end of the entire range?

Here is the code I tried.

`ActiveCell.EntireColumn.Select`

`Selection.Copy`

`Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight`

**Actual Result**:
Multiple columns are select and copied correctly but inserted at the end of the range. That is, Columns A, B and C are correctly selected and copied, and then inserted as D E and F, where: A=D, B=E and C=F.

Comment: Maybe like this... get the range of the header (code assume that there won't be a blank cell in between of row 1) ---> `Set rgHdr = Rows(1).SpecialCells(xlConstants)` ... then loop from right to left of the rgHdr `For i = rgHdr.Columns.Count To 1 Step -1`. Create rg variable as the first cell of rgHdr ---> `Set rg = rgHdr(1, i)`. The code assume that there won't be a blank row in between data of rg.column ... so the copy code line : `Range(rg, rg.End(xlDown)).Copy` then paste insert `rg.Offset(0, 1).Insert Shift:=xlToRight` ... next loop `Next`.

Answer (score 1):

### Duplicate Columns

- Why these complications?
- Flexibility. You don't have to select entire columns or adjacent columns. The selected cells can be in any row or column and they can be selected in any order. The line `Set rg = Selection.EntireColumn` takes care of all issues that might occur without it.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub DuplicateColumns()
    
    If Selection Is Nothing Then Exit Sub ' no selection
    If Not TypeOf Selection Is Range Then Exit Sub ' not a range
    
    Dim rg As Range: Set rg = Selection.EntireColumn
    
    Dim arg As Range, crg As Range, a As Long, c As Long 
    
    For a = rg.Areas.Count To 1 Step -1
        Set arg = rg.Areas(a)
        For c = arg.Columns.Count To 1 Step -1
            Set crg = arg.Columns(c)
            crg.Copy
            crg.Offset(, 1).Insert xlShiftToRight, xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
        Next c
    Next a
    
End Sub
```

Comment: This worked perfectly well, thank you!
Follow up question: how can I now hide the original column that was duplicated?

I didn't add that in my original question as I had that part solved. But with this new option, my original hiding code is not working.

Comment: I guess, right below `crg.Offset...`, add `crg.Hidden = True`.

Comment: I was adding it right before it and wouldn't work. Changing the order did the trick! Amazing, thanks!